# A categorical method to, say, determine the cardinality of a group

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

I am trying to figure out how much one can figure out about an object using category theory. Ideally, any property that is well defined up to isomorphism should be computable using only category theory. Let us say that we are trying to figure out how many elements are in a group? For a set, we could "simply" count the morphisms to it from the terminal object. Obviously, this wouldn't work. Is there a "categorical" method to find the cardinality of a group? If one wants a rigorous definition of what I mean by "categorically", here is your compass and straightedge:

1. You have an abstract symbol for the object in question.
2. For any two abstract symbols for objects $G$ and $H$, you can get abstract symbols for $Hom(G,H)$
3. For any abstract symbol for an object $G$, you can get the abstract symbol for $id_G$.
4. For any two abstract symbols for morphisms $f$ and $g$ such that $f \circ g$ is defined, you can get the abstract symbol of $f \circ g$
5. In terms of the objects and morphisms for abstract symbols you already have, you can get the abstract symbol of any object that uniquely (up to isomorphism) satisfies a given universal property (if needed, I can clarify this.)

Using a finite number of steps, I am trying to find the cardinality of the group. Note for example, you can't take the forgetful functor from $Grp$ to $Set$ (since you can't compute a functor on an abstract symbol.)

I am thinking one method would be to count how many automorphisms there are, but am I not sure how to get the cardinality of the group from this.

If these set of "rules" are too restrictive, it would be interesting to see how they could be lightened to make it possible.

Comment: $|G| = |Hom(\mathbb{Z},G)|$

Comment: @StevenGubkin What universal property does $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy (my group theory is quite weak.) (Also, if you put in an answer with the universal property, I would accept it.)

Comment: The answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7793/what-are-the-auto-equivalences-of-the-category-of-groups gives a universal property for Z (namely, that of being a minimal generator)

Comment: A homomorphism from Z picks out a unique element of your group, namely the image of 1.

Comment: @StevenGubkin should I turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: As a related notion, the rings can be characterized categorically since the only non-trivial automorphism of the category of rings is the mapping $R\mapsto R^{op}$ where $R^{op}$ maps a ring to its opposite ring. See the paper The Automorphism Class Group of the Category of Rings by Edwin Clark and George Bergman.

Comment: In a different, but similar question over at MSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656279/can-we-rediscover-the-category-of-finite-abelian-groups-from-its-morphisms/656526#656526 Martin Brandenburg and I gave a long list of examples how one can go about characterizing group theoretical notions in terms of the category of groups (in that particular case: the category of finite groups which is seems to be a harder case than the category of all groups)

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use the forgetful functor, how do you define the category of groups? In my eyes the forgetful functor is about as categorical as you can get it.

Comment: What does cardinality means if you only consider it internally to $\bf Grp$? Is the cardinality of $\Bbb{Z/6Z}$ and $S_3$ the same there? What about $\bigoplus_{i\in\Bbb Z}\Bbb{Z/2Z}$ and $\Bbb Z$ do they also have the same cardinality? And what if we compare those to $\bigoplus_{n\geq3}S_n$, what then?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: See Steven's answer. The group order can be categorially characterized as $|Hom(\mathbb{Z},G)|$ (of course one has to characterize $\mathbb{Z}$ in categorial terms first, but that can be done as well)

Comment: @Johannes: But how do you characterize $|\hom(\Bbb Z,G)|$? Isn't it another group in $\bf Grp$? Isn't that a bit of cheating? Isn't it almost the same as just saying $|G|$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies a certain universal property (since it seems like steven is unlikely to make his comment an answer, I will make it an answer and credit him once I understand what the universal property is.)

Comment: @PyRulez: Yes, but you still don't answer my question. If you just go from calculating $|G|$ to calculating $|\hom(\Bbb Z,G)|$, how is this "calculating the cardinality in categorical methods"? You just calculate the cardinality of a different group. Is it *really* different than just using $|G|$ directly?

Comment: $hom(\mathbb{Z}, G)$ is not a group, it is a set of morphism. I would consider counting the morphisms between two objects "categorical."

Comment: @PyRulez: Right, my bad. In any case, if you consider counting morphisms "categorical", who am I to stand in your way, then. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila What else is "categorial" if not "doing all the stuff one can do with sets in the special case of hom-sets" ? Counting elements is stuff you can do with sets. It's almost the only stuff you can do with sets...

Comment: @Johannes: Maybe categorically it's all you can do with sets. But this is not all you can do with sets in general. Anything you can do, you can do with sets. But to your original (possibly rhetorical) question, I have no idea what is considered "categorical".

Comment: I'm not really satisfied with the $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G)$ manner of answering this question, since evaluating the cardinality of a Hom set seems to me to be a set-theoretic activity rather than a categorical one. A more satisfying answer would be to show that the relation $|G|\leq |H|$ for groups $G$ and $H$ is definable (or not) purely in the category of groups, in some formal language appropriate for that category, one able to mention certain kinds of diagrams and whatnot. The "straight-edge and compass" that needs to be defined is what precisely this formal language is.

Comment: That is, we want to show $|G|\leq |H|$ if and only if $\varphi(G,H)$ holds in the category of groups, where $\varphi$ is some purely category-theoretic statement to be interpreted in that category in a suitable formal language (or prove that there is no such statement).

Comment: For example, can you identify all and only the groups $G$ with cardinality exactly $\aleph_{\omega^2+6}$ by some purely category-theoretic feature? I expect that at least one such group is identifiable this way, and so if we had the equinumerosity relation, we'll have identified them all.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I usually think if hom-sets as being categorical in nature. It would be interesting though to see if you could, not only see if two cardinalities are equal, but also when one is greater than another. Nevertheless, this would probably do better as a separate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bunch of bits and pieces from a bunch of people:

Let us say we are trying to find the cardinality of the Group $G$. First, we select the group, $\bullet$ (unique up to isomorphism) such that for any other group, there is a unique arrow in and out of $\bullet$. Now, we select a group $\mathbb{Z}$, unique up to isomorphism, such that it only has two idempotent homomorhpisms, and it admits at least two morphisms to any other group besides $\bullet$ (thanks [Todd Trimble](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194047/a-categorical-method-to-say-determine-the-cardinality-of-a-group#comment483051_194066)). Now we find how many morphisms there are from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $G$ (special thanks to [Steven Gubkin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194047/a-categorical-method-to-say-determine-the-cardinality-of-a-group#comment482973_194047)). This is $|G|$.

### Proof

The group $\bullet$ is the trivial group. Now, the group $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers satisfies the properties above via the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107443/if-two-groups-g-and-h-both-have-a-nonzero-homomorphism-to-all-other-groups). Now, for any other group $H$ which satisfies the properties, we know that there is a nontrivial morphism $f : H \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Now the image of $f$ will be a group of integers, and so must be multiples of a given integer $n$ (which won't be zero since $f$ is nontrivial.) We can take a map from this to all the integers, so that we can turn $f$ into a surjection $\bar f$. Now, we make a morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $H$, $i$, such that $i(1) = x$ for some $\bar f(x) = 1$.

Since $\bar f(i(n)) =\bar f(x+x+x+\dotsb)=\bar f(x)+ \bar f(x)+ \bar f(x)+\dotsb=1+1+1+\dotsb=n$, $\bar f \circ i = id_\mathbb{Z}$. This means that $i \circ \bar f$ is idempotent, and since $i(\bar f(x)) = x$, it is not the zero morphism. Since $H$ has only two idempotents (the zero morphism and $\operatorname{id}_H$), and $i \circ \bar f \neq 0$, $i \circ \bar f = id_H$. (Thanks [Slade](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107443/if-two-groups-g-and-h-both-have-a-nonzero-homomorphism-to-all-other-groups#comment2258099_1107443).) Therefore they are inverses. Therefore we can select $\mathbb{Z}$ up to isomorphism.

For each element of $G$, $x$ we make a morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $G$, $h$, such that $h(n) = n * x$. Also, for any morphism $h: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G $, $h(n) = n * h(1)$, where $h(1)$ is an element of $G$. Therefore, the morphisms between the integers and $G$ are in one to one correspondence with the elements of $G$. Therefore $|\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, G)| = |G|$.

$\square$

Comment: What do you mean, $\mathbb{Z}$ has "two idempotents"? As an additive group, $\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique idempotent, same as any other group: because $x^2=x$ implies $x=e$ (the identity). And multiplicatively, it is not a group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I meant idempotent homomorphism, namely a homomorphism, say $f$, such that $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$. I have clarified it now. (Category theorists think by default in homomorphisms instead of elements. Sorry for the confusion.)

Comment: In the very first comment after your ***Question***, Steven Gubkin said all there was to say (one could add the categorical characterization of $\ \mathbb Z,\ $ but that's trivial).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, to be fair, PyRulez did repeatedly ask StevenGubkin to turn his comment into an answer (starting with http://mathoverflow.net/questions/194047/a-categorical-method-to-say-determine-the-cardinality-of-a-group#comment482975_194047).

Comment: @LSpice -- true! (about selecting answers). I was thinking about earlier precedents on MO of selecting one's own answer.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński Hm, what's the "trivial" categorical characterization of $\mathbb{Z}$ you had in mind? (Categorical characterizations of $\mathbb{Z}$ have been offered in other comments, but it's a slight stretch I think to call them "trivial". Remember that we're restricting ourselves to the first-order language of categories, interpreted in the category of groups.)

Answer (score 10):

Every object $c$ in every category satisfies a universal property; it's universal for maps into or out of $c$, or in other words it represents the functors $\text{Hom}(-, c)$ or $\text{Hom}(c, -)$. So rule 5 certainly needs to be clarified. Once we have the ability to name any object we want we can of course just name $\mathbb{Z}$ and hence name the underlying set functor $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, -)$.

In any case, I think your conditions are much too restrictive. I think a natural example of a categorical method of answering this question would be to describe some categorical property which is satisfied uniquely by $\mathbb{Z}$ (but not necessarily a universal property).

In fact here is such a property: it's a theorem that the free groups are precisely the cogroup objects in $\text{Grp}$. $\mathbb{Z}$ is the unique such group which is indecomposable with respect to coproduct.

Comment: Here is a proposal for a criterion by which one might give a negative answer to a question of this form: I would say that cardinality is not a categorical property if there were some automorphism of $\text{Grp}$ sending the underlying set functor $\text{Grp} \to \text{Set}$ to a non-isomorphic functor. The above argument shows this isn't the case; in particular it implies that every automorphism of $\text{Grp}$ fixes $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Moreover, it's an exercise in Freyd's Abelian Categories (pp. 31-32) that any automorphism of $\text{Grp}$ is uniquely isomorphic to the identity. See this answer by Reid Barton in a thread linked to already by dhy (in a comment under the original post).

Comment: Continuing: Freyd's answer to Qiaochu's suggestion is that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the unique (up to isomorphism) group which admits more than one homomorphism to any nontrivial group and such that its only idempotents are the trivial ones $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Todd: I'm not sure what the claim about idempotents means here; do you mean idempotent endomorphisms?

Comment: Oh, I meant endomorphisms here.

Comment: @ToddTrimble What do you mean by idempotent on a homomorphism? Do you mean that $e$ is an idempotent of $f$ if $e \circ e \circ f = e \circ f$?

Comment: @PyRulez: the two conditions are separate. The first one is "admits more than one homomorphism to any nontrivial group" and the second one is "the only idempotent endomorphisms are the trivial ones."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Any hints as to the proof that these conditions identify $\mathbb{Z}$ uniquely up to isomorphism?

Comment: PyRulez, suppose $G$ is such a group. Then there is a nonzero homomorphism $G \to \mathbb{Z}$; since the image is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, there is a surjective $p: G \to \mathbb{Z}$. This $p$ admits a section, i.e., a homomorphism $i: \mathbb{Z} \to G$ such that $p i = 1_\mathbb{Z}$. Then $i p: G \to G$ is an idempotent, and clearly not the zero idempotent, and therefore $i p = 1_G$; thus we have proved $p: G \to \mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

In the category of all groups, the epimorphisms are precisely the surjective mappings according to [this encyclopedia of mathematics structures](http://www.math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/groups). Therefore, since the epimorphisms are surjective, one can recover the lattice of all normal subgroups of a group simply by taking all the epimorphisms where we regard two epimorphisms $f:A\rightarrow B_{1},g:A\rightarrow B_{2}$ as being equivalent if there is an isomorphism $i:B_{1}\rightarrow B_{2}$ with $if=g$ and we order the epimorphisms with domain $A$ where if $f:A\rightarrow B_{1},g:A\rightarrow B_{2}$, then $f\leq g$ if there is some epimorphism $j:B_{1}\rightarrow B_{2}$ with $jf=g$.

Similarly, the monomorphisms in the category of all groups are precisely the injective mappings, so one can recover the lattice of all subgroups of a group from the category of groups. If $G$ is a group, then the compact elements in the lattice of subgroups are precisely the compact elements in the lattice of subgroups of $G$. It is easy to see that a group is infinite if and only if it has infinitely many finitely generated subgroups:
if $G$ is infinite and $G$ contains an element of infinite order $a$, then $\{\langle a^{n}\rangle|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are infinitely many finitely generated subgroups. If $G$ has no element of infinite order, then set $a\simeq b$ if $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle$; then each equivalence class in $G$ has finitely many elements, so $G$ has infinitely many equivalence classes and hence infinitely many finitely generated subgroups.

I now claim that if $G$ is infinite, then there are $|G|$ many finitely generated subgroups of $G$.  Clearly, there are $|G|$ many finite subsets of $G$, so there can be at most $|G|$ many finitely many subgroups of $G$. If we let $\simeq$ be the same equivalence relation as before where $a\simeq b$ iff $\langle a\rangle=\langle a\rangle$, then each equivalence class can have at most finitely many elements, so there are $|G|$ equivalence classes in $|G|$. Therefore $G$ has at least $|G|$ finitely generated subgroups.  We therefore conclude that for infinite groups, the cardinality $|G|$ is equal to the number of compact elements in the lattice of all subgroups of $G$ which can be described in terms of categories.

Comment: And then what do you do?

Comment: The epimorphisms with domain $A$ form a preordered class $\mathcal{J}$. One can turn $\mathcal{J}$ into a partial order and in fact a complete lattice simply by letting two elements in $\mathcal{J}$ be equivalent if there is an isomorphism between the ranges preserving the original map.

Comment: And then how do you get the cardinality?

Comment: It does not appear that one can get the cardinality of a group simply by taking the lattice of normal subgroups. It just seemed like getting information of a group from the category of groups seemed to be in the spirit of your question.

Comment: I wanted to see if specifically chosen properties that one does not think as categorical "categorically." Although your example is nice, it is somewhat trivial.

Comment: The case where one considers monomorphisms instead of epimorphisms gives us the cardinality of infinite groups and it is just as simple as the case with epimorphisms.

Comment: I don't see how the epimorphisms allow you to recover the lattice of all subgroups. If $G$ is a simple group, then the only epimorphisms with domain $G$ are those into the trivial group and those into $G$ itself. In the former case, there is but one epimorphism; in the latter case, you get $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, and all maps are equivalent since given two automorphisms $f,g\colon G\to G$, we can let $i=gf^{-1}$ to get $if=g$, hence $f\leq g$ holds for any pair. So my lattice contains two elements: how did I recover the lattice of subgroups of $G$ from this?

Comment: Arturo Magadin. I meant to say that from the epimorphisms one recovers the lattice of all normal subgroups instead of all subgroups.

Comment: I was wondering... In any case: there is a nice, simple proof that all group epimorphisms are surjective due to Linderholm; you can see the proof [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.math/DV2iNGdzQ8U/AEMrOtkjQG0J)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194047/a-categorical-method-to-say-determine-the-cardinality-of-a-group#comment483017_194050):  [Linderholm - A group epimorphism is surjective](https://doi.org/10.2307/2317336).